# Infinite group $G$ with subgroup $H$ such that $xHx^{-1} \subset H$, for some $x \in G$

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

> Give an example of $G$ an infinite group ($\#G=\infty$) having a
>   subgroup $H$ such that $xHx^{-1} \subset H$, for some $x \in G$. (That
>   is, $xHx^{-1} \neq H$.) [Hint: Take $G = S_z$, $H = \{f \in G : f(x) = x \text{ if } x < 0\}$.]

What exactly is $S_z$ here? The set of permutations of the integers? If so, I do not see how an example would follow from the hint. Could anyone point me in the right direction without spoiling the answer too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more I couldn't be sure, but it seems fair to guess that $S_z$ is the permutation group of the integers.

What about the function $g(x)=x+1$ ? (I claim $gHg^{-1} \subsetneq H$.)

Explanation:

> Then $gfg^{-1}(x)=gf(x-1)=g(x-1)=x$ for all nonpositive $x$, but we can't permute zero, so it's not all of $H$.

Comment: In short,  $Stab(\{n,n-1,n-2\cdots\})$ denotes the permutations fixing $n,n-1,n-2,\cdots$. Then  $Stab(\{0,-1,-2,\cdots \}$ and $Stab \{-1,-2,-3,\cdots \})$ are conjugate with one properly contained in other.

Comment: @Max Thank you so much. I really appreciate it. I was stuck thinking of $x$ as finite permutation (it would not be possible then right?). Quite clever to use the negative integers as a "protective sheet" to prevent permutation of 0 under $H$.