# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, and let $K=\{x∈G:xax^{−1}∈H\text{ for every }a∈H\}$, prove that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, and let $K=\{x\in G:xax^{-1}\in H \text{ for every a}\in H\}$, prove that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

[image]

I don't know how to prove the inverse part of (a), that $x\in K \implies x^{-1}\in K$.

This is an exercise from Pinter's book, and I found an anwser from [here](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~mstemper2/Math/Pinter/Chapter05D), but I don't get the `iff` part of the proof, i.e., the following argument:

> Let $p\in K$. Choose an element $a\in G$, and let $b=pap^{-1}$. Then, $b\in H$ iff $a$ is.

- If $a\in H$, then $b\in H$: ok, this is obvious.
- If $b\in H$, then $a\in H$: why?

Note that the problem on the 1st edition of the book is the 1st paragraph of this post, whereas in the answer page, the exercise 7 is stated differently (i.e., added `iff` part) as shown in the 2nd edition:

> 7. Let H be a subgroup of G and let K = {x∈G: xax-1∈H iff a∈H}.

So it seems there were some upates...

Comment: Hint: $a\mapsto xax^{-1}$ is a bijection $H \to xHx^{-1}$. Prove it.

Comment: Your initial statement 7. (a) is not true in general. But your revised version of 7 at the end of your post is correct.

Comment: @Derek Thanks for your comments. So you mean that the revision in the 2nd edition of the book (i.e, adding `iff`) for this exercise is *necessary* (i.e., not redundant)?

Comment: Yes. There is a counterexample to 7. (a) in the answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599694/)

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** as pointed out in the comment below this answer, this reasoning only really applies to the case where $G$ is a finite group, which I believe is what the author had in mind.

---

Here's one argument that works. Note that the map $f_p:H \to H$ given by
$$
f_p(a) = pap^{-1}
$$
is invertible (in the infinite case, injective with left-inverse) with $(f_p)^{-1} = f_{p^{-1}}$. Thus, $f_{p^{-1}}$ defines a map from $H$ to $H$ which is to say that if $pap^{-1} \in H$, we have
$$
f_{p^{-1}}(pap^{-1}) = a \in H
$$
as desired.

In other words, the iff in the second definition is redundant.  Given that $xax^{-1} \in H$ for every $a \in H$, it must also hold that $xax^{-1} \in H$ IFF $a \in H$.

---

That being said: with the above argument, we have $p \in K \iff f_p$ maps $H$ to $H$.  From this perspective, the fact that $p \mapsto f_p$ defines a homomorphism makes it clear that $K$ will be a subgroup.

Comment: This is not correct. Without the "iff" the statement 7. (a) is false in general. A counterexample is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599694/) for example. If $f_p$ is not surjective, then it is not invertible.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate a bit on the last sentence of your answer? "$p\mapsto f_p$ defines a homomorphism" in what sense? and why "it's clear K will be a subgroup"?

Comment: Probably you meant the following? For finite $H$, $f_p$ is a permutation of $H$; All permutations of $H$ is the group $S_H$ (with operation of permutation composition);  If $K\to S_H$ is an *isomorphism*, then $K$ is a group too, thus it's a subgroup of $G$. So we only need to show that $K\cong S_H$: it's easy to show that $K\to S_H$ is injective, how to show that $K\to S_H$ is surjective (meaning that permutations of $H$ must be in the form of $xHx^{-1}$)?

Comment: @bruin In the infinite case, the correct statement is $p \in K \iff f_p$ is a permutation on $H$ as you have noted.  With this observation, my point was that if $p,q \in K$, then we have
$$
f_{pq} = f_p \circ f_q
$$
which means that $f_{pq}$, being a composition of permutations on $H$, must be a permutation.  Likewise, 
$$
f_{p^{-1}} = (f_p)^{-1}
$$
and the inverse of a permutation of $H$ must be a permutation of $H$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

For your first question,use the defining property of $K$ with $a^{-1}$, which belongs to $H$ since $H$ is a subgroup.

Second question:  express $a$ in function of $b$.

Incidentally, $K$ is called the *normaliser of* $H$, as it is the greatest subgroup of $G$ containing $H$ in which $H$ is normal.