# Proof Check: If $\phi_H=\{xH\mid hxH=xH, \forall h\in H\}$ and $N=\{g\in G| gHg^{-1}=H\}$ Prove: $|\phi_H|=(N:H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I don't have question, I just want a verification of my proof attempt for the following question:

> $G$ is any group which might be infinite, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, where $H$ is finite.
>
> Define $L$ as the set of all left cosets of $H$ in $G$. Let $\phi_H=\{xH\in L \mid hxH=xH, \forall h\in H\}$ and $N=\{g\in G\mid gHg^{-1}=H\}.$
>
> **Prove:** $|\phi_H|=(N:H).$

**My attempt**

If I can show $\frac{N}{H}=\phi_H$, then it automatically completes the proof.

(1) to show $\frac{N}{H}\subseteq \phi_H$

$\forall gH\in \frac{N}H$, since $g\in N$, we have $h(gH)=(hg)H=(gh')H=g(h'H)=gH$, for $\forall h\in H$.

Therefore, $gH\in \phi_H$

(2) to show $\phi_H\subseteq \frac{N}{H}$

$\forall xH\in \phi_H$, to show $xH\in \frac{N}{H}$, it is equivalent to show $x\in N$. Since $N$ is a subgroup of $G$, to show $x\in N$, it is equivalent to show $x^{-1}\in N$.

$\forall h\in H$, since $xH\in \phi_H$, then $\exists h_1, h_2\in H$, such that $hxh_1=xh_2$

$\Rightarrow x^{-1}hx=h_2 h_1^{-1}\Rightarrow x^{-1}hx\in H\Rightarrow x^{-1}H (x^{-1})^{-1}=H\Rightarrow x^{-1}\in N\Rightarrow x\in N$.

Therefore, $xH\in \frac{N}{H} \quad \Box$

Comment: It's typically written $N/H$, not $\frac{N}{H}$, because it indicates left cosets of $H$ in $N$.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the horizontal way $N/H$ means left cosets of $H$ in $N$, but the vertical way $\frac{N}{H}$ means the right cosets of $H$ in $N$?

Comment: No. The group of right cosets of $H$ in $N$ is denoted $H\setminus N$. This is not often used (due to its use in set theory).

Comment: Your $\phi_H$ is not clearly defined because you do not tell that $xH$ is a priori any coset *in G/H* (subject to the condition after the sign $\mid$), i.e. $x$ is a priori any element *in G*. I would write it $\phi_H=\{C\in G/H\mid\forall h\in H,~hC=C\}.$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thank you for telling me this convension, but what I really mean by writing $\frac{N}H$ is that it is the quotient group, because $H$ is normal in $N$, sorry for the confusion.. @Shaun

Comment: Right, sorry I forget to claim that part, yes, what I want to say is the set of all left cosets of $H$ in $G$ such that $\forall h\in H$ preserve it. I have edited this part, thank you. I don't have question, I just want a proof check... @AnneBauval

Comment: Well this is a question. You must made it explicit at the beginning of your post, and add the corresponding tag. Note that my answer contains this proof check.

Comment: I see, yes, I have added proof check. Thank you.

Comment: Actually you had not (made it explicit at the beginning of your post, and added the corresponding tag), so I just did it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Usually, it's clear from the context that the quotient group is meant by $\frac{N}{H}$. This does not mean that it is advisable to use it though. Just use $N/H$.

Comment: Sorry I don't get your point, what I thought is since $H$ is normal in $N$, in this case $\frac{N}H=N/H$, right? If $H$ is NOT normal in $N$, then I need to write $N/H$, because it doesn't form a quotient group. You suggest to write $N/H$ because it works for both cases (normal or not normal), do I understand correctly? @Shaun

Comment: Yes, @MathFail.  Even though left and right cosets are equal for a normal subgroup, it is still customary to use $N/H$.

Comment: okay, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $H$ is finite, your proof is correct but could be much shorter: for any $x\in G,$
$$\begin{align}xH\in\phi_H&\iff\forall h\in H,~x^{-1}hxH=H\\&\iff\forall h\in H,~x^{-1}hx\in H\\&\iff x^{-1}Hx\subseteq H\\&\iff x^{-1}Hx=H\\&\iff H=xHx^{-1}\\&\iff x\in N.\end{align}.$$

If $H$ is infinite, your statement may be false because [$gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$ does not imply $gHg^{-1}=H$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599694). The flaw in your proof is when you claim that your $N$ is closed under $x\mapsto x^{-1}.$